# Java IDE to designing a GUI

Tags: java, software-development, gui, ide

Is there an IDE that allow us to make Java GUI similar to using C# and visual studio? That is, dragging and dropping buttons etc?

Comment: This Question is vague and unfocused. Do you want a desktop or mobile app? If so, will you be working in [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)), or [SWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit)? Or a web app ([Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com), etc.)? Consult a discussion site such as http://www.JavaRanch.com/ to get orientated. Once your specific needs are clear, with a list of criteria, come back to post here (searching here first, of course).

Comment: @ Harikrishnan Did my post answered my question

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking how can I 
Designing a Swing GUI in NetBeans IDE.
You can use Netbeans IDE. 
You can refer to official doc 
[official documentation](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html) 
Or this youtube tutorial

[YOUTUBE tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAxa-I6GnOXVbILvpPphiRytXJYyGGHyG)

Answer (score 0):

Never have used any such tool for building Java GUI myself, but posibly [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) could be what you search.